# Export a bash environment variable from a Makefile that is the populated from a command

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to create a `Makefile` that will export a bash environment variable that is populate by a command:

```
RESOUCE_GROUP=containerresourcegroup
STORAGE_ACCOUNT=mycontainerstorage
SHARE_NAME=containers

do:

    AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING=$(shell az storage account show-connection-string --resource-group ${RESOUCE_GROUP} --name ${STORAGE_ACCOUNT} --query connectionString -o tsv)
    export AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING
```

When I run the task, the variable isn't populated correctly:

```
$ make do
AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING=DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net;AccountName=mycontainerstorage;AccountKey=[removed]
export AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING
```

What am I missing?

Comment: be more explicit, what does "isn't populated correctly" mean?